# MySQL: Very impossible Join (4 me)

Tags: mysql, join

I can't explain this, I make an example.

TABLE 1

```
Client_ID |Name     |Sector   |
----------|---------|---------|
40302025  |Peter    |commerce |
40302028  |Paul     |business |
40302030  |Moreno   |Services |
40302055  |Jack     |commerce |
40302074  |Mark     |Services |
```

TABLE 2

```
Client_ID |Name     |Dollars   |
----------|---------|----------|
40302025  |Peter    |200.000,00|
40302025  |Peter    |300.000,00|
40302028  |Paul     |200.000,00|
40302028  |Paul     |200.000,00|
40302030  |Moreno   |100.000,00|
40302030  |Moreno   |200.000,00|
40302030  |Moreno   |500.000,00|
40302055  |Jack     |10.000,00 |
40302055  |Jack     |20.000,00 |
40302055  |Jack     |500.000,00|
40302055  |Jack     |30.000,00 |
40302074  |Mark     |20.000,00 |
40302074  |Mark     |5.000,00  |
40302074  |Mark     |10.000,00 |
40302074  |Mark     |20.000,00 |
40302074  |Mark     |40.000,00 |
```

Now I want to SUM the Table2.Dollars  referring to the table1.sector with this result:

Results

```
Sector    |Total_dollars|
----------|-------------|
commerce  |1.060.000,00 |
Services  |895.000,00   |
business  |400.000,00   |
```

Firts row: Sum of the dollars of Peter and Jack (Both on "Commerce" Sector)

Second row: Sum of the dollars of Moreno and Mark(Both on "Services" Sector)

Third row: Sum of the dollars of only Paul (on "Business" Sector)

NOTE: I haven't a "Sector" Field in Table 2

I am about to go mad

I think there's a Join of a Join of a Join .... and so on... I don't know the way to begin

Any idea?

Very Thanks

Oscar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT t1.sector,SUM(t2.dollars)
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.client_id = t2.client_id
GROUP BY t1.sector;
```

The `JOIN` makes all the columns from both tables available for you to work with.:

```
          Table1              |        Table2
----------|---------|---------|----------|---------|----------|
Client_ID |Name     |Sector   |Client_ID |Name     |Dollars   |
----------|---------|---------|----------|---------|----------|
40302025  |Peter    |commerce |40302025  |Peter    |200.000,00|
40302025  |Peter    |commerce |40302025  |Peter    |300.000,00|
  ...
```

Then, what you want is sector from table1 and the `SUM` of dollars from table2. You then `GROUP BY` sector, so that the result  of the SUM is calculated for each sector.

---

p.s.: You should have the client name only in one table, and just use client_id whenever you want to reference that client.

Comment: Can I be ashamed? Very Thanks. Oscar